# Using MySQL Workbench on Linux Mint 18

Tags: mysql, linux-mint

I've never had a MySQL install go smoothly. Not Mac. Not Windows. And now Linux joins the mess.

I installed mysql-server via Software Manager after a failed attempt with linuxbrew. I can actually run it in terminal, but I have to use `sudo` which seems odd. I don't see any examples where the user has to use `sudo`.

On top of that, when I run MySQL Workbench I can't connect. I get the error, `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install mysql from apt-get install mysql-server ? it probably asked you for a default root password (Ubuntu like systems usually do). If you have forgotten it, have no fear, the password can be reset

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix

Try doing this as linux root (sudo -i), if that doesn't work try

```
sudo -i
sudo mysql
```

and give it a shot.

Alternatively, sudo, connect to mysql and create another user account with full privileges something like

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to someother user identified by ...
```

Comment: I'll try it, but it doesn't seem to be a password issue. I can run `sudo mysql` from the command line and access my databases. It's mainly using workbench to access the dbs that's an issue, and  it's odd that I have to run sudo in the first place

Comment: yep, the root system user in ubuntu can connect without a password if you did not set a default password at installation time.

Comment: so my original answer is still valid but also see update

Comment: The answer is correct, but the method I used is different. I've never been able to get the reset password instructions to work. I ended up removing everything.
`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*`  
`sudo apt-get autoremove`  
`sudo apt-get autoclean`  
`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`  
`sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql`

Then I reinstalled it with `sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server`

Comment: ouch! that's painfull! hopefully you didn't have important data

Comment: Nope. It was a fresh linux install. Apparently the issue is that I had just pressed enter when it asked me to setup a password thinking it would result in empty string `''`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect remotely with root database user since the default user created doesn't have access on '%' (remote access).

Create another user with limited rights (secure) and use it for workbench.

creating user on mysql:

```
create user test@'%' identified by 'test_user_password';
grant all on *.* to test; -- you can specify specific permissions/databases
flush privileges;
```

Try these credentials with workbench.

As far as the linux command line is concerned

```
mysql -uroot -p
-- hit enter, no password and see if you can get connected
```